# Cardview layout not displaying in the right design pattern

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

Currently I have a container that holds in my cards in a way that my first and and 6th card are horizontally elongated while cards 2 to 5 are vertically elongated. I am currently using bootstrap to achieve this, but the layout is not something I exactly want.

Here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

And here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

I need help with how I can have 1 card in the row with a lower height and the initial 2 cards in the second row to take over the whitespace that will be left because of the first card having a lower height.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-fermat-z5ibx?file=/src/App.tsx

Code:

```
<div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-12">
            <div className="row">
              {posts &&
                posts.map((item, idx) => (
                  <div
                    className={
                      idx === 0 || idx % 5 === 0
                        ? "col-md-6 col-sm-6"
                        : "col-md-3 col-sm-3"
                    }
                    style={{
                      cursor: "pointer",
                      paddingLeft: "5px",
                      paddingRight: "5px"
                    }}
                  >
                    <img
                      src={item.img}
                      alt=""
                      style={{
                        minHeight: "280px",
                        objectFit: "cover",
                        height: "100%",
                        width: "100%",
                        paddingBottom: "10px"
                      }}
                    />
                    <div className="topLeft">{item.Title}</div>
                  </div>
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should take advantage of the actual [bootstrap 4 card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/). Secondly, There are plenty of ways you can go about.

#1. Use only two columns and then play with height of items and flex order:

https://jsfiddle.net/n31v7yr6/

Demo:

```css
.card-group2 {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-group2 col-sm d-flex flex-wrap bg-primary align-content-center">
      <div class="card w-100 h-50">1</div>
      
      <div class="card w-50 h-25">2</div>
      <div class="card w-50 h-25">3</div>
    </div>
     <div class="card-group2 col-sm d-flex flex-row-reverse flex-wrap bg-primary align-content-center">
      <div class="card w-100 h-50 order-1">1</div>
      
      <div class="card w-50 h-25">2</div>
      <div class="card w-50 h-25">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#2. Use css grid for two column and have similar code as above for flexbox.

#3. Don't use `row > col` at all and just use bootstrap `card-group`.

#4. If you don't want to change the html(generated from the backend?) then just play with individual items heights' and use position relative to change vertical positions.